# Find two markers based on the first marker and the kilometer of the same road to draw the line

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polyline

Well, so hard to draw the line with distance is kilometer with googlemap,
I have a question:

I want to draw the line based on only point, example:

1. I have the "point",
2. I find the left point and the right point with distance is 5 kilometers on the same road.
3. I draw the line with left point and the right point.

=> At step 2, how to find the left point and the right point ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4RSm.png)

Sorry for my bad English,
Any help from any framework can solve it :'(

I tried with Flutter but there are many restrictions from Googlemaps to resolve it!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.